# Interpreting coeftest results; z-test; t-test, unfamiliar with the output

Tags: r, t-test, z-test

I am using [coeftest](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lmtest/versions/0.9-40/topics/coeftest) to run z- and t- tests on a few different pieces of data. The output comes in this form:

fit <- lm(dest_flood ~ type_flag, data = runsample)
coeftest(fit)

```
t test of coefficients:

              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)     0.0412     0.0162    2.54    0.011 *
type_flagprox   0.0448     0.0184    2.44    0.015 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

However, I am used to t- tests and z-tests resulting in data that looks more like this:

```
    prop.test(x=c(11, 81), n = c(267 , 942), p = NULL, alternative = "two.sided",
              correct = TRUE)
    
data:  c(11, 81) out of c(267, 942)
X-squared = 5, df = 1, p-value = 0.02
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.0770 -0.0126
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
0.0412 0.0860
```

Where the information you get is that the t-test/z-test basically tell you if differences are significant or not. Do I interpret the first bit of come with the estimated coefficients the same way I would interpret output from a OLS - where a 1 unit increase in type_flagprox is a 0.0448 unit increase in the outcome? If that were output from a binary model, would I interpret it like a logistic regression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is about how to interpret the t test as a linear model.  I've recreated your data below and will use it in my explanation:

```r
library(tidyverse)


runsample = tribble(~type, ~y, ~n,
        '_flagprox', 1, 11,
        '_flagprox', 0, 267-11,
        'a', 1, 81,
        'a', 0, 942-81) %>% 
  uncount(n)
```

The data you've used to fit it consist of two types: $x$ is a binary indicator variable (where $x=1$ when `type == _flagprox` else 0).  $y$ is also a binary variable (i.e. 1 or 0).

As you've mentioned, you can do a test of proportions with this data.  When you do this, the estimated difference comes out to be 0.0448

```r
runsample %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  summarise(meany = mean(y)) %>% 
  arrange(meany) %>% 
  pull(meany) %>% 
  diff %>% 
  round(., 4)

[1] 0.0448
```

The associated p values and confidence intervals are shown in the output of prop.test.  Now, let's turn our attention to the linear model.  The model you've fit is

$$ y = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 x $$

When $x=0$, then $y_0$ is the mean of the reference group (whatever it is).  When $x=1$ then $y_1$ is the mean of the `_flagprox` group.  So the difference $\Delta$ in those is...

$$ 
\begin{align}
\Delta &= y_1 - y_0\\
&= (\hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1) - \hat{\beta}_0\\
&=  \hat{\beta}_1 
\end{align}$$

So the coefficient of `type_flagprox`, or the slope, is the estimated difference, and that is exactly what we see in the output

```
lm(y~type, data=runsample) %>% 
  summary

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ type, data = runsample)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.08599 -0.08599 -0.08599 -0.04120  0.95880 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  0.04120    0.01620   2.543   0.0111 *
typea        0.04479    0.01835   2.440   0.0148 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2647 on 1207 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.00491,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.004085 
F-statistic: 5.955 on 1 and 1207 DF,  p-value: 0.01482
```

Because the data are binary (and only coded as continuous) the "one unit increase" interpretation is right but for the wrong reasons.  Clearly you can't have a two unit increase in `type` since it is only a variable with 2 categories.  A better interpretation for the data you've used is...

> $\hat{\beta}_1$ is the estimated difference between the group represented by $x=1$ and the group estimated by $x=0$.

The associated confidence intervals can be obtained by using the `confint` function, but be aware that they may differ slightly between the confidence intervals shown in `prop.test` in general due to the use of a z statistic in the latter and t statistic in the former.

Comment: Thanks so much, just to confirm I am understanding this correctly. Let's say the outcome was a continuous variable, then the estimated coefficient (0.04479) is still the difference in the outcome variable for x = 1 compared to the group of x=0, it's just that the outcome group has a larger range (like if it went from 0-100 instead of 0 or 1). Is that correct?

Comment: @tchoup Correct.